# Bootstrap Navwalker parent link issue in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wp-nav-walker

I see variations on this question have been answered but I am struggling to figure out how to apply to my site.

When I click on a top-level link that has children, I can get it to either toggle to show the sub-nav items OR go to the linked page. I would like to have both (click once to toggle, second click to go to link, or toggle on hover). Here's the navwalker code I'm working with. I have tried it multiple ways. I'm new to coding anything beyond basic html and css. Any help appreciated!

The original code had `$atts['href']          = '#';`

instead of `$atts['href']          =  ! empty( $item->url ) ? $item->url : '';`

I have also tried  `$atts['data-hover']   = 'dropdown';`

instead of  `$atts['data-toggle']   = 'dropdown';`

Here is the version I have now in the file class-wp-navwalker.php, and below that, the html it resolves to.

```
// Initialize array for holding the $atts for the link item.
        $atts           = array();
        $atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? $item->attr_title : '';
        $atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target ) ? $item->target : '';
        if ( '_blank' === $item->target && empty( $item->xfn ) ) {
            $atts['rel'] = 'noopener noreferrer';
        } else {
            $atts['rel'] = ! empty( $item->xfn ) ? $item->xfn : '';
        }

        // If the item has_children add atts to <a>.
        if ( $this->has_children && 0 === $depth ) {
            $atts['href']          = '#';
            $atts['data-toggle']   = 'dropdown';
            $atts['aria-haspopup'] = 'true';
            $atts['aria-expanded'] = 'false';
            $atts['class']         = 'dropdown-toggle nav-link';
            $atts['id']            = 'menu-item-dropdown-' . $item->ID;
        } else {
            if ( true === $this->has_schema ) {
                $atts['itemprop'] = 'url';
            }

            $atts['href'] = ! empty( $item->url ) ? $item->url : '#';
            // For items in dropdowns use .dropdown-item instead of .nav-link.
            if ( $depth > 0 ) {
                $atts['class'] = 'dropdown-item';
            } else {
                $atts['class'] = 'nav-link';
            }
        }
```

and the html...

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-navbar-collapse-1" aria-controls="bs-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div id="bs-navbar-collapse-1" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul id="primary-menu" class="nav navbar-nav" itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
            <li  id="menu-item-367" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-home menu-item-has-children dropdown menu-item-367 nav-item"><a href="http://sal-new:8888/" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" id="menu-item-dropdown-367"><span itemprop="name">About Us</span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="menu-item-dropdown-367">
                    <li  id="menu-item-101" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-101 nav-item"><a itemprop="url" href="http://sal-new:8888/about-us/our-story/" class="dropdown-item"><span itemprop="name">Our Story</span></a></li>
                    <li  id="menu-item-102" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-102 nav-item"><a itemprop="url" href="http://sal-new:8888/about-us/rc/" class="dropdown-item"><span itemprop="name">RC</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li  id="menu-item-99" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-92 current_page_item active menu-item-99 nav-item"><a itemprop="url" href="http://sal-new:8888/our-work/" class="nav-link" aria-current="page"><span itemprop="name">Our Work</span></a></li>
            <li  id="menu-item-362" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type_archive menu-item-object-event menu-item-362 nav-item"><a itemprop="url" href="http://sal-new:8888/events/" class="nav-link"><span itemprop="name">Events</span></a></li>
            <li  id="menu-item-364" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type_archive menu-item-object-resource menu-item-364 nav-item"><a itemprop="url" href="http://sal-new:8888/resources/" class="nav-link"><span itemprop="name">Resources</span></a></li>
            <li  id="menu-item-104" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-104 nav-item"><a itemprop="url" href="http://sal-new:8888/something/" class="nav-link"><span itemprop="name">Contact</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The HTML output looks okay-ish, seems like the parent link has a proper `href` set now. _“click once to toggle, second click to go to link”_ - that you would have to facilitate on the client side, using JavaScript. Click event handler for the relevant links, _count_ the clicks, decide what to do based on that. Maybe also involve some sort of time check to see how far apart those clicks happened.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how to do that. I was favoring having the submenu open on hover but realized it isn't a good option because it won't work for tablets and mobile phones. So I am circumventing the issue by changing how I structure the navigation instead.